# Typescript Error Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript, ionic3

What am I doing wrong here?

```
for (var yearx = 0; yearx < (2018 - 2011); yearx++){
    json.course[i].year[yearx] = {'value':eval(2011 + yearx),'term':[{'value':e}]};
//add terms`
```

…causes:

> Typescript Error
>
> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `+""` to `e` to convert it to a string:

```js
for (let yearx = 0; yearx < (2018 - 2011); yearx++){
    json.course[i].year[yearx] = {'value':eval(2011 + yearx),'term':[{'value':e +""}]};
```

Comment: I think [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is clearer: `{'value': e.toString()}`

Answer (score 0):

`eval` accepts a string as input. You pass in `2011 + yearx` where `yearx` is a number, so the compiler complains. I'm not sure why you need to `eval` anything. Just remove that function call and save `2011 + yearx` to the `value` key.